# Some elements of multi-dimensional array incorrectly reading zero

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to use a multi-dimensional array to store data, however, some of the indexes of the array don't seem to be working right.  I get correct data for most of the elements but a portion of them will all read zero even though the values that were read in are not zero.  The array ends up looking something like this:

```
-3.238467  -3.237679  -0.487128  -3.237634  -3.238513  -3.239868  
-3.239361  -3.238660  0.000000  -3.238610  -3.435949  -3.437109  
-3.622402  -3.621796  0.000000  -3.621911  -3.436662  -3.437587  
-3.237072  -3.236771  0.000000  -3.237329  -3.237926  -3.238605  
-3.227221  -3.227291  0.000000  -3.228477  -3.229173  -3.229775  
-3.204790  -3.205429  0.000000  -3.207087  -3.207956  -3.208255  
-2.618961  -2.621088  -2.622552  -2.623831  -2.624973  -2.625057
```

Even if I check the values like this:

```
for(j=0; j<(num_cell_y); j++) {
    for(i=0; i<(num_cell_x); i++) {
      ...
      ...
      ...
      grid[i][j] = u_avg;
      printf("%f\n", u_avg);
      printf("%f\n", grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

I get two different values printed out:

```
-3.237675
0.000000
```

Has anyone else had this happen to them or know of something I may have missed that is causing this?

Comment: your grid array dimension is mismatched with your loop, and also your not summing anything from the array in your code

Comment: There's a good chance that the array declaration is wrong. You should post complete code that demonstrates the problem (something that readers might compile if they wish). Without seeing the declaration, all we can do is take a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you need to fill the array in this order -

```
grid[j][i] = u_avg;  // Note the indexes being reversed.
```

Comment: Why should looping over j first instead of i make a difference as long as I am consistent through the entire code?  It only cares what i and j are for that specific iteration, it doesn't depend on any of the previous iterations so it could be done in any random order I want.

Comment: To me what's strange here is that it printed out two different values even though the previous line was supposed to set the two values equal to each other.  It's like it just ignored that line or something.

Answer (score 1):

there is a mistake in order this should be

```
grid[j][i] = u_avg;
```

what is happening with your order `grid[i][j] = u_avg;`

the j is in the outer loop so it once fixed for i till `i<(num_cell_x);` and the array is multidimensional and according to your code it changing the outer array like

```
i    j
a[0][0]=>
a[1][0]=>
a[3][0]=>
```

this is not correct so if you do j and than i

```
j    1
a[0][2]=>array(1=>'',2=>'',...)
a[1][0]=>
a[3][0]=>
```